# Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'Password')' when an ASP .Net Core is ran

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I downloaded a source code from somewhere. Running it will cause an error, "System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'Password')'"

Here's the code that causes error

```
string GetSqlConnectionString()
{
            var connStr = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"))
            {
                Password = Configuration.GetValue<string>("SQL_PASSWORD"),
                Authentication = SqlAuthenticationMethod.SqlPassword,
            };

            return connStr.ToString();
}
```

My `appsettings.json`

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

Can anyone help me what's wrong?

Comment: You need an appsetting entry for "SQL_PASSWORD", which is not there as you can see in the json file.

Comment: What is your problem? Do you need to know how to get a connection string from config file  or  how to use  a builder?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a connection string section in appsettings.json, something like this:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {  "DefaultConnection": "user id=userid;pwd=password;data source=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;initial catalog=DBName;"}
```

If you want. you can move the password outside the connection string as well.

Answer (score 0):

you have to change your appsettings.json

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=mydb;Integrated Security=False;User ID=myid;Password=mypassword;"
  },
    "AllowedHosts": "*"
  }
```

and your method

```
public string GetSqlConnectionString()
{
 return Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
}
```

or if you  just need a password, add  a password section to an appsettings

```
.....
"AppIdentitySettings": {
        
        "Password": {
            "Value":"mySqlPassword",
        }
},
.....
```

and code

```
var password = Config.GetValue<string>("AppIdentitySettings:Password:Value");
```